# sqlsrv not showing up in my phpinfo

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, phpinfo

I have just installed php 5.3 on windows server 2008 R2 running IIS7.
phpinfo() is working fine.

now I want to see if I have correctly installed the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server.

I downloaded from here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=80E44913-24B4-4113-8807-CAAE6CF2CA05#RelatedResources

I have dropped the 2 dlls (php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll and php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll) into the PHP\ext folder and referenced them in the php.ini  I restarted the server.

But when I run phpinfo()  I'm not seeing any reference to sqlsrv  is that normal? or should there also be a section of phpinfo() dedicated to these sqlsrv extensions?

Error logging is on but there are no errors coming up in the php-errors.log referring to sqlsrv. Both files php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll and php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll have been added (non thread safe version for IIS), php5.dll is present in the php install folder.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with the php.ini not having saved for some strange reason.  Now is all good. To anyone else that lands here, make sure you've got 
extension_dir="C:\PHP\ext" in your php.ini   though my problem was elsewhere...